# The output bin file is larger than 16 bytes than plain text bin file; when we use opnessl AES ECB command to test

Tags: openssl

I'm newer to openssl. I try to use openssl AES-128-ECB command to encrypt/decrypt bin file. But I found the test.bin is 512 bytes; but aes_ecb_encrypt.bin is 528 bytes. Per my understanding, the size of encrypt file generated by AES ECB command should be equal to plain text size(test.bin). Don't know why openssl append 16 bytes at the end. Anyone can give me some comments?

Thanks

openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-ecb -in test.bin -out aes_ecb_encrypt.bin -K "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f"

openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -in aes_ecb_encrypt.bin -out aes_ecb_decrypt.bin  -K "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f"

Answer (score 0):

That’s called padding. It’s needed because ECB is a block cipher with defined block sizes. It can only handle full blocks.

cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Padding

PS: Please note, that ECB is insecure.